# His job is a taxi driver

Tags: grammar

1. His job is a taxi driver.
2. He is a taxi driver.
3. His job is to drive a taxi.

---

Are the three sentences all the same and grammatical?

Comment: Yes, they are all grammatical. They all state an person's occupation. There is no referential context of how there are being used in a larger statement,  to make a judgement on whether they fit as descriptive as a particular conjunctive reference, or not.

Answer (score 3):

#1 is problematic. When someone says "His job is a", what follows is almost always a subjective description of the job:

- His job is a lot easier
- His job is a tough one
- His job is a PITA

Saying "his job is a taxi driver" feels mismatched to me. You can use something like [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) to see the usage pretty clearly. See also the ELL question [“His job is a teacher” Looking for a correct way to express this thought](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/106722/41273).

---

#2 is fine. You should be able to find examples all over the web that use this form. For example: [She is a Software Developer, She is Victoria Offoma](https://nigeria.girlsintech.org/2017/03/14/she-is-a-software-developer-she-is-victoria-offoma/) or [He's a pirate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He%27s_a_Pirate).

---

#3 is... interesting. It's perfectly grammatical. However, I think I'd be unlikely to say it, unless his job title is something other than "taxi driver" or if you were listing duties for several people's jobs and wanted stylistic consistency. You usually see this format used when there's no corresponding job title ("[Your Job is to Find a Better Job](http://sourcesofinsight.com/your-job-is-to-find-a-better-job/)") or if the job title doesn't give a good explanation of the duties like in the following:

> My job is to go into a client organization, assess their SharePoint needs and produce a custom product according to their specifications. — [Software Engineer - SharePoint Platform](https://www.careercast.com/page/software-engineer-sharepoint-platform)

Answer (score 0):

[A taxi driver](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/taxi-driver) is a person whose job is to take people in a taxi to the place they want to go to in return for money.

You would say:

1. He is a taxi driver.
2. He has his job as a taxi driver.
3. His job is to take people in a taxi to the place they want to go to in return for money.

Comment: I would only say #2 when asked to explain why he's not starving or something similar.

Comment: We could add 'He has the job of a taxi driver'. I would say that no. 2 has a different context, listing things about him rather than what is job is, but I like the fact you have included it.

Comment: @TrevorChristopherButcher edit your comment first you misspelled his to is, then you can help me [edit my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/470621/edit) .

Comment: @michael.hor257k The one that has been so far omitted, and is perhaps the correct version of no.1, is "His job is that of a taxi driver".  But it wouldn't be used in casual conversation - more in some official statement, news report, or for clarification, e.g. "Her boy-friend does not own the smart car that he drives, his job is that of a taxi driver".

Comment: Technically "a person whose job is to take people in a car to the place they want to go to in return for money" is an Uber driver (or Lyft, etc). Taxi drivers only drive taxis.

Comment: Idk, I used this for the reference: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/taxi-driver @Laurel. Btw you can help me [edit my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/470621/edit), ty :)

Comment: Meh, sounds like they wrote that before ride sharing was a thing. Before that, it might have been obvious that "car" referred to "taxi" (which is technically a type of car). It sounds like that section might have been written with nonnative speakers in mind (who might not know what a taxi is).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question pedantically: yes they are all *grammatically* correct, and yes they are "the same" in the sense of conveying the same information unambiguously.

However, #1 ("his job is a taxi driver") sounds wrong—not grammatically, but semantically.  He and his job are not the same logical entity.  He himself is not the act of driving, and by the same token,  his job is not a person.

At a stretch, you could say "his job is taxi driver" without the article. That sounds a little stilted/unidiomatic but it's not incorrect—I would think of it as an abbreviated way of saying his job *title* is "taxi driver",  or as something analogous to writing "occupation: taxi driver" on a form.